# Where can I find downloadable smartphones data rating?

Tags: data-request, products

Currently I need to find smartphone product data rating for testing. Does anybody have more info on this? Is there someone who provides a downloadable dataset like that? Or maybe some technique to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get Amazon's reviews for the products (including smartphones) though it's Product Advertising API here: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Check the T&C's on usage though.